# Oracle query in jasper not returnig data where data type is varchar?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I am running below query in *Jasper* (using Oracle DB) but returning empty because the data type of the name is `varchar` but it is returning if I *select the column* which has number or date as a data type.

```
select name from student_data;
```

attached is the screenshot of the property. and below is the query

select name, date_of_birth from student_data. i will have data for date_of_birth but name column is empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqaLl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Jaspersoft-Studio and also the older version iReport have the Problem, that they are implementet with the wrong datatype. for example

```
DB column: ID(int)
iReport_FIELD: ID(BigDecimal)
```

But you should be able to simply change the Datatype of the Field.

1. Go to the "Fields" part of your Navigation-Window and select the Field with the wrong Datatype
2. On the Property-Window you can see one of The Properties of the Fiels is "Field Class", There you can change the Class of your `name` Field.

Comment: The data type for varchar in java is string and when we run the query it does come up as the class type string but doesn't show any results.

Comment: Could you show us the iReport/JasperReport Field and it's propertys and the `CREATE TABLE` statement or the Output of the `SELECT` Query you used?

Comment: i have already attached the image with my question.                                                  Thanks.